# Need a previous and next button above the keypad

Tags: java, android, keyboard

I want to show the virtual keyboard with Prev, Next Buttons above the keyboard.

When the user clicks prev button, cursor should move to the previous edit-text input field and clicking on next button should go to the next edit-text field in the view.

I want to use those buttons in my own activity. How can I do this?

Comment: you can override OnKeyDown() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieve by adding android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" to activity 
element within the manifest. E.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.codename.android"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
        >

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
</manifest>
```

This prevents the view from resizing when the virtual keyboard is displayed.

Comment: And If i want to show next and done button hit from tha keypad..when i click on the edittext keypad opens and include next button to move in next editext box. and done button to finish typing.. how can i do this..

Comment: Add Intent to onClickListener of the "Next" button to move in the next edittext box.And use android:editable="false" to done button to lock typing.

Answer (score 2):

You can set proper IME option for the Edittext in the Layout.

```
android:imeOptions="actionNext"
```

and for done

android:imeOptions="actionDone"

Answer (score 1):

```
Android code to override the "Done" button in my EditText field:

myEditField.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {

               InputMethodManager imm =(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
               imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getWindowToken(), 0);//hide the keyboard.

                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```