# Add next and done button hit from the keypad-Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, transparency

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Need a previous and next button above the keypad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032601/need-a-previous-and-next-button-above-the-keypad)

I want to show next and done button hit from the keypad..when i click on the edittext,![enter image description here][1] keypad opens and include next button to move in next editext box. and done button to finish typing.. how can i do this..